# Show or Hide fields in Twig Template in function of ChoiceType Field Value

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, dynamic, twig

I would like to show or hide some fields dynamically in function of the value of my ChoiceType field (registrationForm.roles).
For example, I'm trying here to hide the field firstname if the value selected for roles is 'Center'.

I have tried this:
The template

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    {% for flashError in app.flashes('verify_email_error') %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ flashError }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <h1>Register</h1>
    {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.roles) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.name) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.firstname) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
            label: 'Password'
        }) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.phone) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.NISS, {label: 'NISS'}) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.BCE, {label: 'BCE'})  }}


    {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
    {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document
            .getElementById("registration_form_roles")
            .addEventListener("changes", function(e) {
                if(e.target.value = 'Center'){
                    document
                        .getElementById("registration_form_firstname").hide();
                }
            });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The Form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('roles',ChoiceType::class,[
                'choices'=>[
                'Specialist'=>'Role_Specialist',
                'Parent'=>'Role_Parent',
                'Center'=>'Role_Center',],])
            ->add('name')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('NISS')
            ->add('BCE')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
        // Data transformer
        $builder->get('roles')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($rolesArray) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return count($rolesArray)? $rolesArray[0]: null;
                },
                function ($rolesString) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return [$rolesString];
                }
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

To summarize, I want my field to change in dynamically in function of the value of the role.

I have checked the symfony document but can't find what I want. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Check your jQuery selector. It might not be `registration_form_roles`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although it seems to be the right Id :/ I have added a screenshot to my question :)

Comment: Check `if(e.target.value = 'Center'){`: what if you use `===`?

Comment: It doesn't work either but I noticed an error in the console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at register:10

Comment: I don't have that error anymore. I add the script in the block body. But still not working. ..

Comment: `"change"` not `"changes"`

Comment: Indeed. Thank you ! Although it's not working to hide the field but I have tried with another span id='test' and it worked. It seems the jQuery selector is not correct. 
Thank you to the both of you ! :)

Comment: Ok, it's solved. The value to test on was 'Role_Center' and not 'Center'.
Thank you again !